# In C, how can I get the appropriate memory alignment for my platform?

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I am writing a custom arena allocator, which allocates blocks of varying sizes from a large buffer. However, I want to ensure that the addresses returned by it are always appropriately aligned, similarly to how `malloc` always returns suitably-aligned pointers.

```c
#define ALIGN 16

char buffer[2048];
char *next = buffer;

// Allocates a block of memory, ensuring that "next"
// is always a multiple of ALIGN.
void *alloc(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *ret = next;
    next += (nbytes + ALIGN - 1) & ~(ALIGN - 1);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    void *p1 = alloc(1);
    void *p2 = alloc(5);
    void *p3 = alloc(17);
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to find out what is the appropriate memory alignment that I should use for the platform my code is being compiled for? Or should I just set ALIGN to a large enough constant, as I do in the code example?

Comment: The heuristic (and value) you're using is reasonable.  The C18 standard has a type `max_align_t` that is the type with the most stringent alignment requirement (see §7.19 Common Definitions `<stddef.h>`).  I am not sure that it was a part of C11 — and my usual online resource for C11 is currently offline.  There are architectures where function pointers require 16-byte alignment; I'm not aware of any more stringent alignments for basic types, though sometimes graphics manipulations (bitblit operators) require page-aligned bitmaps.

Comment: Dont ask me why, I dont remember it. But i remember that the allocators should be 64 bit alinged. I will search the source. Edit. Found [it](https://wiki.osdev.org/James_Molloy%27s_Tutorial_Known_Bugs#Problem:_kmalloc_isn.27t_properly_aligned)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `max_align_t` is specified by [the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: C 2018 contains “only technical corrections and clarifications” (C 2018 M.1 1). It would not have added something like `max_align_t`.

Comment: Good points, Eric and Andrew.  I put my uncertainty down to under-caffeination and the absence of the online resource for checking and my laziness about going to my other machine where I have my copy of C11.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to find out what is the appropriate memory alignment that I should use

If it's going to be simple `obstack` implementation, you could pass the type alignment requirements to your `alloc` function, thus possibly reducing memory usage.

```
#include <stdalign.h> // from C11

void *super_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size, size_t count);

int *five_ints = super_alloc(alingof(int), sizeof(int), 5);

#define SUPER_ALLOC(type, count)  \
       ((TYPE*)super_alloc(alignof(TYPE), sizeof(TYPE), (count)))
double *seven_doubles = SUPER_ALLOC(double, 7);
```

Before C11 you may write compiler specific code along `#define alignof(type) compiler_specific_code_here(type)`. There are `aligned_alloc` and `posix_memalign`.

> for the platform my code is being compiled for?

When you know the platform, then you know it. Research the documentation of *that specific platform* you are compiling for and find out it's maximum required alignment for any types.

In C11 there is `max_align_t` that you could use and it should be set by your compiler:

```
static const size_t ALIGN = alignof(max_align_t);
```

You could potentially take all types and write a big `MAX(alignof(int), alignof(long int), alignof(double), alignof(long double)` function-switch with all the types.

> Or should I just set ALIGN to a large enough constant, as I do in the code example?

That said, `16` is going to be most probably definitely enough for 99,9% platforms out there, but feel like a waste on platforms with smaller alignment requirements.

Comment: Don't forget to add pointers and (especially) function pointers to the list of types.  Or create a union of plausible types (`unsigned long long`, `long double`, `void *`, `void (*)()` probably suffices) and use that to ensure the alignment.  See K&R for an example of this.